# iTunes library .xml vs. .itl

Tags: itunes, migration

I have iTunes 12.6. I read that after 12.2 iTunes doesn't create .xml to store playlists. Is the .itl the same thing?  Will it have my playlists?  I tried importing the library.itl to my new computer, but nothing happened.  How do I get my playlists to a new computer when using iTunes 12.2 or later?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to add info such as: (1) What type of computers are you migrating from and to (i.e. Mac > Mac, PC > Mac, etc). (2) If from Mac > Mac, do you have a Time Machine backup of the first Mac? (3) How are you trying to import the library?

Comment: I am copying Mac to Mac.  Yes, I have a Time Machine backup of the first Mac, but could not find the .xml file on the most recent backup.  I am guessing that is because iTunes does not use .xml after ver.12.2 (or so I read). I copied all music onto my new machine first in a music folder, then imported it into iTunes.  I don't remember if I drag and dropped or if I used Library>import playlists>music.  Either way, all music was in iTunes, but playlists were not.  Hope that clarifies, sorry I was ambiguous at first, just frustrated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the reason you've run into problems is that you've tried to manually migrate across your iTunes data from your Time Machine Backup.

Without knowing exactly what you did, if you copied the entire iTunes folder from your TM backup to your new Mac, one thing you can try is to tell iTunes where that folder was copied to. To do this you would:

- Open iTunes
- Go to iTunes > Preferences (or just press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>)
- Select the Advanced tab
- Now you'll see an option where you can set your iTunes Media Folder location

**Migration Assistant**

Since you're migrating to a new Mac, you'd probably be better off starting again and using Migration Assistant to transfer all your data across. This will give you the option of migrating what you choose from a Time Machine backup or directly from your other Mac (if you have a way of connecting to it). Migration Assistant also provides other options.

To use Migration Assistant:

- On your new Mac, open Migration Assistant (by default it's in your Applications > Utilities folder)
- If you happen to have another user logged in, you'll be prompted to log them out first. If not, you'll see an Introduction screen instead.
- Click on <kbd>Continue</kbd>
- You may be prompted to enter your password - if so enter it and click <kbd>OK</kbd>
- You'll now be asked how you'd like to transfer your data.
- Select the option applicable to you (most likely the first one which allows you to transfer from a Time Machine backup)
- Click <kbd>Continue</kbd>
- Follow the prompts to migrate the data you want

**Note:** This process may take some time.

For more information see [Move your content to a new Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350).